# Python: request to add a variable in url

Tags: python, request

Since I am using a for loop to request a URL which changed with a constant number, how can I parsed the variable in?

```
    total_page = 4
    for y in range (total_page):
        variable = 20*y+1
        base_url = 'https://abcd.com/r='
        url = ''.join([base_url, variable])
        finviz1 = requests.get(url)
```

However, an error occurred

```
    url = ''.join([base_url, variable])
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, int found
```

How to eliminate the error?

Comment: `variable` is an integer, while `string.join` expects a list of **strings**. Convert variable to string by `variable = str(variable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects all elements of the array to be a string, whereas you are passing `variable` as an integer. Convert it into a string before passing it, like this:

```
url = ''.join([base_url, str(variable)])
```